# How to add a user to a discount group in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am creating a **discount group** for employee of the store.
I could create the discount row and assign it to a user, but I can't assign the employee discount group to a specific user.

What I need to proper assign the discount group to a customer.

These are the lines from my impex files.

> essential-data.impex

```
INSERT_UPDATE Discount;code[unique=true];value;currency(isocode) 
;employee-discount;15
INSERT_UPDATE UserDiscountGroup;code[unique=true]
;employees
```

> catalog.impex

```
INSERT_UPDATE DiscountRow;$catalogVersion;discount(code)[unique=true];pg(code)[unique=true];ug(code)[unique=true];value
                         ;               ;employee-discount          ;                     ;employees            ;15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing one command to make a relation between Usergroups and DiscountGroup.

Also my error was to refer directly, inside discount row, a user group instead of a discount group.

The user group *employees* is already define in user-groups.impex

> essential-data.impex

```
INSERT_UPDATE Discount;code[unique=true];value;currency(isocode)
;employee-discount;15
INSERT_UPDATE UserDiscountGroup;code[unique=true]
;employee-discount-group
UPDATE Usergroup;uid[unique=true];userDiscountGroup(code)
;employees;employee-discount-group
```

> **catalog.impex**

```
INSERT_UPDATE DiscountRow;$catalogVersion;discount(code)[unique=true];ug(code)[unique=true]  ;value
                         ;               ;employee-discount          ;employee-discount-group;15
```